# C dynamic arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am creating program in C which allocates dynamic memory for array and I made function which shows those numbers, but sadly I don't know how to add exception when memory isn't allocated and to write "Can't show anything because memory wasn't allocated". Here's my code.

```
void printing(int *data, int size){
    if (data != NULL){
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
            printf("%d\n", data[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Nothing to show\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-the-functions-malloc-and-free

Comment: C doesn't have built in exception handling. There are however 3rd party libraries you can use. Google it!

Comment: What do you mean by "add exception"? The code you're showing checks for a null pointer, which makes sense. Maybe it should check that `size` is reasonable somehow. But it's unclear what else you wish to do. From the looks of it, memory is being allocated outside of this function you are showing. Dynamic memory allocation functions, like `malloc`, return NULL when a failure to allocate occurs.

Comment: Also, you can simply go `if (data)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int * data = malloc(count * sizeof(int));
if (data) printf("Allocation succeeded");
else printf("Allocation failed");
```